# Endfloat seems to suppress subnumbering of tables

Tags: subfloats, endfloat

I have been using the endfloat package to put my figures and tables to the end of the paper. Besides I also use subtables environment from the subfloat package to sub-number some tables, e.g., Table 1a and Table 1b. However, as long as I use the endfloat package, the sub-numbering of tables failed. For example, in the following MWE, there are only two tables. Using the endfloat package, the tables put at the end of the paper start from table 2 and table 3 (not even from table 1?). In the text, the markers show [Table 1 about here.] and [Table 2 about here]. In contrary, if I turn off the endfloat, everything goes well. Does anyone know how to make the sub-numbering work still using endfloat? Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{eurosym,geometry, pdflscape,booktabs,,subfloat, lipsum}
    \usepackage[notablist, nofiglist]{endfloat}
    \geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-15]

    \begin{subtables}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \caption{Effects of privatization on general performances 1}\label{perform1}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule\midrule
   Privatization year & -0.001 & 0.006 &  & -0.026 & -0.028\*\* \\ 
     & (0.018) & (0.012) &  & (0.019) & (0.014) \\ 
    One year after & -0.108\*\*\* & -0.114\*\*\* &  & -0.103\*\*\* & -0.107\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.014) &  & (0.018) & (0.015) \\ 
    Two years after & -0.146\*\*\* & -0.144\*\*\* &  & -0.152\*\*\* & -0.162\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.013) & (0.016) &  & (0.016) & (0.017) \\ 
    Three years after & -0.155\*\*\* & -0.156\*\*\* &  & -0.126\*\*\* & -0.125\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.018) &  & (0.015) & (0.019) \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Effects of privatization on general performances 2}\label{perform2}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule\midrule 
    Privatization year & -0.007 & -0.022\*\* &  & 0.004 & -0.028\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.010) &  & (0.019) & (0.013) \\ 
    One year after & -0.043\*\*\* & -0.069\*\*\* &  & -0.032\* & -0.066\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.015) & (0.011) &  & (0.018) & (0.015) \\ 
    Two years after & -0.079\*\*\* & -0.113\*\*\* &  & -0.058\*\*\* & -0.088\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.014) & (0.012) &  & (0.022) & (0.016) \\ 
    Three years after & -0.077\*\*\* & -0.094\*\*\* &  & -0.066\*\*\* & -0.097\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.013) & (0.013) &  & (0.015) & (0.016) \\ 
    \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{subtables}

    \lipsum[16-20]

    \processdelayedfloats
    \lipsum[21-22]
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution but at least it will move the tables as sub-tables (and not as regular tables) to the end:

```
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{subtables}{table}
```

Complete document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym,geometry, pdflscape,booktabs,,subfloat, lipsum}
\usepackage[notablist, nofiglist]{endfloat}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{subtables}{table}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]

\begin{subtables}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \caption{Effects of privatization on general performances 1}\label{perform1}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule\midrule
   Privatization year & -0.001 & 0.006 &  & -0.026 & -0.028\*\* \\ 
     & (0.018) & (0.012) &  & (0.019) & (0.014) \\ 
    One year after & -0.108\*\*\* & -0.114\*\*\* &  & -0.103\*\*\* & -0.107\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.014) &  & (0.018) & (0.015) \\ 
    Two years after & -0.146\*\*\* & -0.144\*\*\* &  & -0.152\*\*\* & -0.162\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.013) & (0.016) &  & (0.016) & (0.017) \\ 
    Three years after & -0.155\*\*\* & -0.156\*\*\* &  & -0.126\*\*\* & -0.125\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.018) &  & (0.015) & (0.019) \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Effects of privatization on general performances 2}\label{perform2}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc} \toprule\midrule 
    Privatization year & -0.007 & -0.022\*\* &  & 0.004 & -0.028\*\* \\ 
     & (0.017) & (0.010) &  & (0.019) & (0.013) \\ 
    One year after & -0.043\*\*\* & -0.069\*\*\* &  & -0.032\* & -0.066\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.015) & (0.011) &  & (0.018) & (0.015) \\ 
    Two years after & -0.079\*\*\* & -0.113\*\*\* &  & -0.058\*\*\* & -0.088\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.014) & (0.012) &  & (0.022) & (0.016) \\ 
    Three years after & -0.077\*\*\* & -0.094\*\*\* &  & -0.066\*\*\* & -0.097\*\*\* \\ 
     & (0.013) & (0.013) &  & (0.015) & (0.016) \\ 
    \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{subtables}

\lipsum[16-20]

\processdelayedfloats
\lipsum[21-22]
\end{document}
```